# Cloudinary images aren't displaying on live site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

Pretty new to Rails, but I'm having an issue getting images to display on a live site. The images are uploaded by the user as part of creating a post, but I'm running into two issues:

1. The media library is not updating when an image is uploaded
2. On localhost the upload works fine and is displayed, however on the live site the images are not being displayed. The page loads fine but the Cloudinary image src generated doesn't point anywhere
   Example:

```html
    <img class="main-post-image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hw2ugvhic/image/upload/vfvhamrbx0jz8rj6y17c2vy4m2gp">
```

New post view:

```html
<div class="text-center mt-3">
  <h1>New post</h1>
</div>
<div class = "main-form-container">
  <div class= "post-form-container">
    <div data-controller="multi-upload">
    <%= simple_form_for [@country, @area, @post] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :summary %>
      <%= f.input :description, as: :rich_text_area %>
      <%= f.input :category , collection: %w(bar restaurant activity nature memory) %>
      <%= f.input :main_image, as: :file, label: "square image only"%>
      <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, data: {action: "multi-upload#addFile"} %>
      <div data-multi-upload-target="files"></div>
      <div class = "d-flex justify-content-center">
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "green-button mt-3"%>
      </div>
      <div class = "text-link text-center mt-2">
        <%= link_to "Go back", country_area_path(@country, @area) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Posts controller:

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.area = @area
    if @post.save
      redirect_to country_area_path(@country, @area)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
  end

  def update
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to country_area_post_path(@country, @area, @post)
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :summary, :description, :category, :area_id, :main_image, images: [])
  end
end
```

Post model:

```html
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :area
  has_one_attached :main_image, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_rich_text :description
  validates :title, :summary, :description, :category, :main_image, presence: true
end
```

Area show view page (where the posts can be viewed)

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-2 pl-2">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><%= link_to @country.name, country_path(@country) %></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><%= @area.name %></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<% unless @posts.empty?%>
  <div class = main-posts-div>
    <div>
    <%= "Welcome to #{@area.name}, #{@country.name}"%>
    </div>
      <%= link_to "New post", new_country_area_post_path(@country, @area), class: "green-button mt-3"%>
    <div>
      <div class="area-main-div">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
          <%= link_to country_area_post_path(@country, @area, post) do %>
            <div class= "post-card">
              <div>
                <% if post.main_image.nil? %>
                  <%= image_tag("https://picsum.photos/300/300") %>
                <% else %>
                  <%= cl_image_tag(post.main_image.key, class:"main-post-image") %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class = "lower-post-card">
                <div>
                  <%= post.title %>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <em><%= post.category %></em>
                </div>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="main-posts-div-blank">
      <div>
        <%= "Welcome to #{@area.name}, #{@country.name}. #{@area.name} is yet to be explored, please document your experience"%><br>
      </div>
      <%= link_to "New post", new_country_area_post_path(@country, @area), class: "green-button mt-3"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Areas controller

```html
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @area = Area.new
  end

  def create
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @area = Area.new(area_params)
    @area.country = @country
    @area.save
    redirect_to country_path(@country)
  end

  def show
    @area = Area.find(params[:id])
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.where(area_id: @area)
  end


  private

  def area_params
    params.require(:area).permit(:name, :country_id)
  end

end
```

**Steps already taken**

Added Cloudinary to Heroku
Created a dotenv file with the cloudinary key
added cloudinary gem
Updated the following:

storage.yml

```html
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
  folder: <%= Rails.env %>
```

development.rb

```html
  config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

What can I try next?

Comment: It could be a couple things, but going from what you posted you probably forgot to add 
`config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary` 
to the production.rb.

Comment: Hey! Yeah that was it, thank you! I'm still pretty new to this

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that might be missing is that active storage does not store the folder as part of the key e.g. `post.main_image.key` would be a random string but is missing `folderName/<random-string>` which you defined in the `storage.yml` file.

I believe you just need to include the folder name in the `cl_image_tag(post.main_image.key, class:"main-post-image")` should be `cl_image_tag("folderName/"+post.main_image.key, class:"main-post-image")`

There probably is a way to pass that dynamically.